# Run a python script in C#

Tags: python, c#

I have a deep learning python script that works completely fine when i run it from the command line. Now what I want to do is run this script on a button press in a C# application.

How do I do this?

I'm trying to call the script with function below. but I get an error:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified'

EDIT:
I changed the python.exe path to another directory which opens the CMD for a split second. but nothing happens.

Also when I change the script file to something that doesn't exist like instead of trying to call face_rec.py I call face_recccccc.py. there isn't any difference in results so its not even calling the script.

```
public void MyFunction()
        {
            string arg = string.Format(@"C:\Users\silen\Desktop\Presentatie\face_rec\face_rec.py"); // Path to the Python code
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Users\silen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python-2.7.5.amd64\python.exe", arg);
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false; // Hide the command line window
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
            Process processChild = Process.Start(p.StartInfo);
        }
```

Comment: If you "cant seem to make it work", please share _what happens instead_. Compiler errors? Runtime errors? Unexpected behavior? Computer catching on fire? Please be mindful no one else can see your screen :)

Comment: You said you can't make it work but you didn't share what you tried to do to make it work, so basically you're just asking us to do all the work for you rather than helping us out. Please help us out rather than expecting us to do all the work.